# java.lang.Error java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console

Help with the following flaw that appears in google play. What can be? 
What code do you need as such? then I leave my android manifest. Which is where I think the problem might be. I informed you beforehand that I do not use admob. But Tappx and applovin.

```
java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [main]
Unity version     : 2017.1.1f1
Device model      : samsung SM-J500M
Device fingerprint: samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BQE1:user/release-keys
Caused by
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.library.walking.e.run (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@20300003@20300003.251657827.251657827:7)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7325)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)



 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.VisionExpresiva.VideoJuegos.Aventura.SuperPionero" android:versionCode="314000031" android:versionName="3.1" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="28" tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.compat,android.support.coreui,android.support.coreutils,android.support.fragment,android.support.mediacompat,android.support.v4,android.support.customtabs" />
  <!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="android.arch.lifecycle.VERSION" android:value="27.0.0-SNAPSHOT" />
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="26.1.0" />
    <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <!--
            Service handling Google Sign-In user revocation. For apps that do not integrate with
            Google Sign-In, this service will never be started.
        -->
    <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.RevocationBoundService" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.permission.REVOCATION_NOTIFICATION" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- The space in these forces it to be interpreted as a string vs. int -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="\ 861637839914" />
    <!-- Keep track of which plugin is being used -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.unityVersion" android:value="\ 0.9.50" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.games.bridge.NativeBridgeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity" android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="3668023e-4e3b-455d-8c55-05eef6fbb41a" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="applovin.sdk.key" android:value="hi_b6-5hAbFb8hLl5pKfZPgcQes1I7gyDhftMpv1Fn_yJn3QWyyoTzOEx7Tennez3XFidOKgHx3xGW8BS4Jt_C" />
        <receiver android:name="com.tappx.unity.InstallReferrerReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Help with the following flaw that appears in google play. What can be? 
What code do you need as such? then I leave my android manifest. Which is where I think the problem might be. I informed you beforehand that I do not use admob. But Tappx and applovin.

Comment: Did you forget to set your ID?
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/881
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/848

Comment: I mean you need to post the code, for us to tell anything.

Comment: What code do you need as such? then I leave my android manifest. Which is where I think the problem might be. I informed you beforehand that I do not use admob. But Tappx and applovin.